# How to catch any touch event on a UIButton that is a subview of a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uibutton, touch

In my app I use an overlay style of presenting help information. Tapping an Info-button in the toolbar overlays a `UIButton` on top of whatever view is currently my main view. It draws an image with help text and arrows pointing to various user interface elements in the current navigation bar and toolbar.

Tapping the Info-button again disposes the `UIButton`, but I also want to get rid of it if the user touches this overlaid button. It works perfectly except for my main view controller, which is a `UITableViewController`.

What I do is create the `UIButton` and add it as a subview of the `UITableView` which is the only view in my main view controller. Then I set it to handle all touch events:

```
[[self masterInfoView] addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMasterInfo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

The `UIButton` has the same size as the table view it now covers, and it goes away of I tap it, but if I make a scrolling gesture (tapping and holding down my finger inside it) the button does not see this as a touch event, instead the underlying table view handles it and scrolls its rows, moving the button along with it.

Before moving to a `UIButton` I worked with a `UIView` and all kinds of gesture recognizers to achieve the same, as well as capturing the `UIResponder` events like `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, all with reasonable results but nothing perfect.

It can not be that hard to make this work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do so and finally I found that you need to set the action when you return the cell to the table data source delegate.

```
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(/*functio name*/:) forControlEvents:/*event name*/]
```

;

I hope this works with you.

Comment: My `UIButton` is not part of the cell I return for a row in my table view. Instead it overlaps the entire table, it display help information for the entire screen at that time, and once tapped, it should disappear. Simply tapping it works, but making a scrolling movement scrolls the underlying table view, which also moves my button up or down with it.

Comment: Make two views in sib file one for the button only and make its background transparent. Then move all the other UI elements to the other view.

Comment: I thought of adding an extra container view that would hold the table view and in which I could add an extra subview for my overlay help text, but I found a workaround described in my answer below this post.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that, as my main problem is caused by the fact that the table view underneath my help text overlay view keeps scrolling even if I do not want it, I might as well use this:

```
[[self tableView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

for as long as the help overlay view (my `UIButton`) is active. Once the overlay is gone, I re-enable scrolling for my table view.

It does solve my problem for now, but it still does not tell me how to keep scrolling events from passing through my overlay and into the table view. It is probably because I add the overlay as a subview of my table view. I should probably make a container view that holds the table view to avoid this in the future (as Mahmoud Fayez somehow suggested as well).

Answer (score 0):

To access any subview of table cell, follow the steps.

```
1.Use the TableView delegate function of "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".
2.By above function you can get the particular index path of tabelcell.
3.Create a local object of any subview using tag value like below.

 UIButton *mybutton=(UIButton *)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:222];
```